Bean e validação com NotBlank
Estou tendo um problema, minha entidade de client está com o seguinte codigo @Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
private String id;
@Column(nullable = false)
@NotBlank(message = "O nome não pode ser nulo")
private String nome;

@Column(nullable = false)
@NotBlank(message = "O CEP não pode ser nulo")
private String cep;

@NotBlank(message = "O endereço não pode ser nulo")
private String endereco;

@Column(length = 5)
private Integer numEndereco;


@NotBlank(message = "O bairro não pode ser nulo")
private String bairro;

@NotBlank(message = "O bairro não pode ser nulo")
private String estado;

@Column(length = 11, unique = true, nullable = false)
@NotBlank(message = "O telefone não pode ser nulo")
private String telefone;

@Column(length = 11, unique = true, nullable = false)
@NotBlank(message = "O CPF não pode ser nulo")
@CPF(message = "o CPF é invalido")
private String cpf;

@Column(unique = true,  nullable = false)
@NotBlank(message = "O email não pode ser nulo")
private String email;

@Column(nullable = false)
@NotBlank(message = "A senha não pode ser nula")
private String senha; 

Quando eu vou ao controller, coloco a validação bean @valid, para conectar e validar os notblank, mas quando insiro no postman consigo colocar a requisição em branco mesmo assim conforme o codigo
@PostMapping()
public ResponseEntity insert(@Valid @RequestBody Client cli){
repo.insert(cli);
return new ResponseEntity(cli, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}[][1]
